# How can I get YouTube data in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build an app that will contain some YouTube videos.
I am using YouTube's API and accessing data using Alamofire but my attempts of data retrieval lead to the following error:

> ```
> {
>     error =
>     {
>         code = 404;
>
>         errors =({
>
>                 domain = "youtube.playlist";
>
>                 location = channelId;
>
>                 locationType = parameter;
>
>                 message = "Channel not found.";
>
>                 reason = channelNotFound;
>
>             }
>
>         );
>         message = "Channel not found.";
>     };
> }
> ```

This is the contents of my `viewDidLoad`

```
let API_KEY = "*********"
let UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID = "PL28aSZBaDzoatmISten8xeFPPuva7l8s5"
let CHANNEL_ID = "PL28aSZBaDzoatmISten8xeFPPuva7l8s5"
let parameters =["part":"snippet","channelId":CHANNEL_ID,"playListId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY]

Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

            if let JSON = response.result.value 
            {
                print(JSON)
            }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Can you confirm a channel exists with that ID?

Comment: For future reference, **NEVER** post API keys out in public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to youtube and find the channel name and and put into

```
 let CHANNEL_ID = "properchannel"
```